# SQL query with WHERE condition that allows empty fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sorry if the title isn't very clear, frankly I don't really know how to explain it in simple words. I have the following problem.

I have this query:

```
SELECT EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE
FROM EQUIPO
     LEFT JOIN ASIGNACION ON EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE = ASIGNACION.EQUI_SERIE
WHERE ASIG_ACTIVA = 'No'
ORDER BY EQUI_SERIE ASC;
```

I would like it to display all the elements from the EQUIPO table that are or are not referenced in the ASIGNACION table, and if they are referenced, I would like it to only display those which have the 'No' value on the ASIG_ACTIVA column. I've tried different things, but I can't quite find what I need from the internet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Guessing*** that `ASIG_ACTIVA` is a column in the table `ASIGNACION` not `EQUIPO` (this is why aliases are important). if so, move the `WHERE` to the `ON`

```
SELECT E.EQUI_SERIE
FROM EQUIPO E
     LEFT JOIN ASIGNACION A ON E.EQUI_SERIE = A.EQUI_SERIE
                           AND A.ASIG_ACTIVA = 'No'
ORDER BY E.EQUI_SERIE ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

change join condition add `ASIG_ACTIVA = 'No'` on join

```
SELECT EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE
FROM EQUIPO
     LEFT JOIN ASIGNACION ON EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE = ASIGNACION.EQUI_SERIE
 and ASIG_ACTIVA = 'No'

ORDER BY EQUI_SERIE ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by restricting your joined table.

```
SELECT EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE
FROM EQUIPO
  LEFT JOIN ASIGNACION ON EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE = ASIGNACION.EQUI_SERIE
                      AND ASIGNACION.ASIG_ACTIVA = 'No'
ORDER BY EQUI_SERIE ASC;
```

By adding the `AND` to your join, you restrict the joined table `ASIGNACION` to only rows that have `no` in column `ASIGN_ACTIVE`
That will get you all rows in `ASIGNACION` that are related and have `no`as value.
Since its a left join, you also get NULL for every row that is either not related, or has `yes`as value.

Answer (score 0):

just as an addition to the other answers, I'll explain you why your query isn't working as you want to, you got the following:

```
SELECT EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE
FROM EQUIPO
     LEFT JOIN ASIGNACION ON EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE = ASIGNACION.EQUI_SERIE
WHERE ASIGNACION.ASIG_ACTIVA = 'No'
ORDER BY EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE ASC;
```

The problem over here is that the where clause is filtering those values that have ASIGNACION.ASIG_ACTIVA as NULL (based on the LEFT JOIN), and as I understood you need the records with NULL or "No" value.
So you can use the solutions given above, or just add to the where clause: "OR ASIGNACION.ASIG_ACTIVA  IS NULL", getting the following:

```
SELECT EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE
FROM EQUIPO
     LEFT JOIN ASIGNACION ON EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE = ASIGNACION.EQUI_SERIE
WHERE ASIGNACION.ASIG_ACTIVA = 'No' OR ASIGNACION.ASIG_ACTIVA IS NULL
ORDER BY EQUIPO.EQUI_SERIE ASC;
```